# Add UIViewController over another but buttons on parent still clickable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

.m file.

```
- (IBAction)switchViewThinking:(id)sendr {

    [self.view addSubview:pick.view];
    pick.view.alpha=1.0;
    [pick animate];
}
```

The view pops up fine. Only the buttons on the parent view are still clickable behind the subview that overlays it.  Also pick is a UIViewController. The parent view has 3 buttons each open a differnt subview. On the subviews buttons are not clickable through UITables or Scrolltext. Linkage is correct and views remove and activate when needed to. Is there a setting I'm missing that would cause this? Whats the best solution to overcome this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to either re-create the buttons on the top layer (maybe as transparent clickable views) or make the top layer smaller so that it doesn't obstruct the buttons below it.  Instead of one large view on top, you could create many smaller views that look like one view,but that still allow the buttons beneath to be visible and clickable.

In any case, I'd advise thinking whether you really want this behavior.  Seems a little like it would not be intuitive for the end user.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Actually I don't want anything on the bottom layer to be clickable at all or seen when the subview pops above it. The subview actually covers up the bottom view very nicely you can't see it which is great. Only if the user drags across parts of the image they will still have access to the bottom layers buttons which is bad.